# Laravel Cannot load Model from Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I was looking at this tutorial for laravel 4 by Dayle Rees. I decided to create my own and I encountered a problem with my Controller not finding the model I created for my table database named 'games'. What could be the problem here? Some screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Game Model` does not belong to the `Games\Controller` namespace.

I assume from your structure that your `Model` is not namespaced, so you have these 2 options:

1. `use Game;` as you did for `View` and `BaseController` or
2. `$data['games'] = \Game::all();`

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you search for a class Game in the namespace Games\Controller\Game. But your Model class is not in this namespace.

You can resolve this by add the use at the top of your class:

```
use Games\Model\Game;
```